# Microsoft Access 2013 keyword search

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a database of FAQs. So one table, call it Table 1, will be a relatively large list of FAQs. These FAQs should be broken up into categories. One category for type A questions, another for type B, and so on, with about 40 separate categories and about 500 FAQs.

My goal is to have a list of table of keywords, perhaps 1000, that will be associated with one or more categories, and which when entered into a search box, pull up the relevant category or categories and all the associated FAQs.

Ideally, this list will be sorted by relevance. That is if category A has a total of 15 FAQs, and category C has a total of 45 FAQs, and all 60 FAQs are pulled up typing in any keywords associated with both category A and category C, it will order those 60 FAQs by which of those 60 contain the closest match to the keyword(s). In other words, one keyword may pull up all of a category or categories FAQs, as each category will have multiple and sometimes overlapping keywords associated with them, but I would like the list of FAQs associated with the categories to be ordered somehow.

1. How do I associate FAQs with categories, and then associate the categories to keywords?
2. How do I create a search bar that will pull up the categories with their associated FAQs?
3. How do I order the FAQs that were pulled up?

Comment: This is way beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow question. You should do some initial reading on databases (tables, relations, primary & foreign keys). Then perhaps take a closer look at the sample database that ships with Access. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the exact data structure of this website. On StackOverflow we have Posts (your FAQ) and Tags (your Keywords). To associate them a many-to-many relationship is used. You can do some [data exploration for how StackOverflow works](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) and base your data model off that.

For example posts for a tag can be retrieved like

```
select 
from Posts p 
inner join PostTags pt
  on p.postId = pt.postId
 inner join Tags t
   on t.tagId = pt.tagId
where t.TagName = 'ms-access'
```

I assume you'd have Categories work the same way. Unless a FAQ can only be in one category at a time, in which case your Category would just be a column in your FAQ table.

Sorting by relevance is much more complicated and something you will need to derive yourself. We don't know what "relevance" means or what your tags are or how FAQs are created, who is interested in them, etc...